# Cannot link HTML to CSS notepad++ link is correct. Glitch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that this is a rookie question and it honestly has my scratching my head with a dropped jaw. I could swear that my reference link to my CSS file is correct I have done this before and I am having the same problem on another project. I am still a rookie but I figured I am past this error. Maybe it is a glitch? Or maybe I need to be humbled a bit. I am using Notepad++. I usually use Sublime text. Is there something that I should do differently? HTML and CSS files are saved in the same folder on my desktop. Thanks

Below is the source code for the first project

Project 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">





<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text.css" href="style.css" />


    <title>HTML5/CSS3 Responsive Theme</title>


    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>


</head>






<body class="body">

        <!--header and logo-->
        <header class="mainheader">
                <img src="logo.jpg"/>


                <!--navigationbar-->
                <nav><ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>                
                <ul><nav>

        </header>






        <!--main content header-->
        <div class="mainContent">
            <div class="content">
                <article class="topcontent">
                    <header>
                        <h2><a href="#" title="First post">First post<a/></h2>
                    </header>

                    <!--functions as secondary header-->
                    <footer>                        
                        <p class="post-info">This post is written by Isaiah</p>
                    </footer>

                    <content>
                        <p>
                        con·tent1
    kənˈtent/
    adjective
    1.
    in a state of peaceful happiness.
    "he seemed more content, less bitter"
     synonyms:  contented, satisfied, pleased, gratified, fulfilled, happy,           cheerful, glad; More
    verb
    1.
    satisfy (someone).
    "nothing would content her"
synonyms:   satisfy, please; More
noun
1.
a state of satisfaction.
"the greater part of the century was a time of content"
2.
a member of the British House of Lords who votes for a particular motion.
                        </P>
                    </content>                  
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>





<!--sidebars-->
    <aside class="top-sidebar">
        <article>
            <h2>Top Sidebar</h2>
            <p>
            Meditation is a practice where an individual trains the mind or induces a mode of consciousness
            </P>
        </article>
    </aside>

    <aside class="middle-sidebar">
        <article>
            <h2>Middle Sidebar</h2>
            <p>
            Meditation is a practice where an individual trains the mind or induces a mode of consciousness
            </P>
        </article>
    </aside>

    <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
        <article>
            <h2>Bottom Sidebar</h2>
            <p>
            Meditation is a practice where an individual trains the mind or induces a mode of consciousness
            </P>
        </article>
    </aside>



<!--footer-->   
    <footer class="mainFooter">
        <p>Copyright Deez Nuts</p>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `type="text.css"` shouldn't have dot in it ..try `type="text/css"`

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: W3Schools validator may be useful for you in this case - https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 3):

Please change link to below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```